# initializer .rb file error happening

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to setup an initializer fb file but I keep getting an error after restarting the rails app. Here is my initializer file called mail_chimp.rb

code inside the rb file

```
MailChimp.configure do |config|
  config.api_key = 'blabla'
end
```

Error I get after restarting rails.

```
myProject/config/initializers/mail_chimp.rb:1:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant MailChimp (NameError)
    from me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/railties-4.0.0.rc1/lib/rails/engine.rb:609:in `block (2 levels) in <class:
```

Anyone know why I'm getting this error. I'm new to rails so first time setting up an initializer file

Answer (score 1):

[**The gem**](https://github.com/mailchimp/mailchimp-gem)'s namespace is `Mailchimp`, not `MailChimp`.

```
Mailchimp.configure do |config|
  config.api_key = 'blabla'
end
```

but that assumes the gem I linked above is the one you're working with *(you haven't specified otherwise)*.

---

**Edit:** now that you've specified your issue more clearly, you need to create your own module. `MailChimp` doesn't exist, so you can't just call `configure` and pass a block to it. One example implementation might be

```
module MailChimp
  extend self

  def api_key
    "bla bla"
  end
end
```

This would let you call `MailChimp.api_key` and get back `"bla bla"`. There are **[gems](https://github.com/binarylogic/settingslogic)** to help you out with this sort of thing, but the best way is to set this 'secret' info in an environment variable. I personally use **[`dotenv`](https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv)**. There is also **[this excellent read](http://railsapps.github.io/rails-environment-variables.html)**.

Comment: I'm not using a gem called Mailchimp. I'm just trying to create a global config in a separate initializer file that happens to be called mail_chimp.rb it could be called help_me.rb. I want to be able to access the api_key from anywhere in the app by calling Mailchimp.api_key

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. So if I have 2 environment files called development.rb & production.rb so how would I set a global config that would be in both without having to duplicate it. For example. config.myApi_key = 'blabla'